# C# Entity Framework Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity, foreign-key

Существует 3 таблицы :

```
public class Films
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set }
    public string Title_Of_Film{ get ; set; }
}

public class Authors
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorsId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Film_actors
{
    [Key]
    public int Flim_ActorsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Films")]
    public int FilmInfoRefId { get; set; }
    public Films FilmInfo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Authors")]
    public int AuthorsRefId { get; set; }
    public Authors Authors { get; set; }

}
```

Последняя таблица - имеет два внешних ключа, которые указывают на внешние ключи 2 первые таблицы.
 Вопрос, когда я буду я буду создавать экземляр класа Film_Actors поля FilmInfo и Authors автоматически заполнятся имея значения внешнего ключа? Или мне нужно всё ручками делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть вы хотели такую структуру:

Есть авторы фильмов, автор может быть автором множества разных фильмов:

```
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        Films = new List<Film>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films { get; set; }
}
```

Есть актёры. Каждый актёр может сниматься в множестве разных фильмов:

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films { get; set; }
}
```

И есть фильмы. В одном фильме может быть несколько авторов фильма и может быть множество актёров:

```
public class Film
{
    public Film()
    {
        Authors = new List<Author>();
        Actors = new List<Actor>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set }

    public string Film{ get ; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

PS Многие-ко-многим ([тынц](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php)). Пример добавления записей есть по ссылке. Да, придётся заполнять руками.